# WiFi won't work, no matter what

Tags: wireless, drivers, internet, broadcom, dhcp

Ok so I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a couple of months now but I just reached the end of my capabilities. The basic problem is that my wifi does not connect to my home network (at least not correctly), so I can't get internet access. The wifi router in my home is not the problem cause all my other devices work fine with it. My impression is that Ubuntu is the problem here. One more thing is that, when I set up a wifi internet-sharing connection with my desktop mac (which is connected to the network by ethernet) I can access this shared connection with the notebook, it's rock-solid stable, connects quickly and delivers internet just perfectly fine. So actually, it seems to be a ubuntu specific problem with that specific wifi network.

Some more specifics on the wifi connection to the network: It technically connects to the router, but it usually take very long till the connection is established, and sometimes it fails to connect completely. After the beginning of the connection (if I get it), I sometimes have a very small time window where internet gets delivered, like 20 seconds to half a minute. After that it's gone. Then, sometimes, I get some internet, but the connection is extremely slow and ultimately stops delivering all together again.

My system is an HP notebook with 12GB RAM , core i5 intel, ubuntu 15.10. My wifi hardware is the (apparently not unproblematic) broadcom BCM43141, for which I use the driver ubuntu recommends me to use (broadcom Linux STA wireless driver source, proprietary).

Approaches I have tried so far:

- I have read many posts and threads from people who have problems with the wifi hardware that I have. One thing I have tried is installing an older version of the driver. Didn't work out. I have read through many other peoples problems that sound similar to mine but never got to a solution.
- I also tried all the config stuff that I know of. I tried dhclient, got a message "RTNETsomething: File exists." So I deleted the dhcp lease file and tried again. New file got created. Problem stays (also after restarting network services etc.). Then I tried it with a static IP instead of DHCP. Wifi was accessed quickly, but still does not deliver internet. Ultimately, I am also suspecting that it would be good to get a new IP from the DHCP, but dhclient always takes ultra long, and when its done, nothing changed and I still have the same IP.
- took a look at the DNS config file and the interfaces file, nothing super strange was found. The resolv.conf file had some DNS server I didnt know about in there so I changed it to the same one my other linux distribution uses, since the wifi works without problems on that one.

At this point I dont know what else to do.

Can anybody help me troubleshoot through this?

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Broadcom BCM43142 802.11bgn 1x1 WiFi Adapter + BT 4.0 combo adapter
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2230]
```

Further note:
I followed the instructions from "[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)", but issue remains.

@ Eduardo Cola:
Here the output

```
# dmesg | grep Wireless
[   12.966209] input: HP Wireless hotkeys as /devices/virtual/input/input9
[   13.966379] wlan0: Broadcom BCM4365 802.11 Hybrid Wireless Controller 6.30.223.248 (r487574)

#ifconfig
eno1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:2b:b8:59:2d:53  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

eno1:avahi Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:2b:b8:59:2d:53  
          inet addr:169.254.5.250  Bcast:169.254.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:3177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3177 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:241496 (241.4 KB)  TX bytes:241496 (241.4 KB)

wlo1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 14:2d:27:ce:ee:11  
          inet addr:192.168.11.22  Bcast:192.168.11.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::162d:27ff:fece:ee11/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:296 errors:0 dropped:81 overruns:0 frame:787
          TX packets:322 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:31547 (31.5 KB)  TX bytes:55495 (55.4 KB)
          Interrupt:18 

# iwconfig
wlo1      IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"4CE6764F111C_G"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 52:E6:76:4F:11:1C   
          Bit Rate=52 Mb/s   Tx-Power=200 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

eno1      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: Also look at the log file where the system keeps all sorts of info. For example `grep wlan /var/log/kern.log`

Comment: Please post the output TO YOUR QUESTION NOT TO THE COMMENTS!!!!

Comment: ...the page tells me to use the comment function if I want to answer to comments

Comment: Please add the outputs of `dmesg | grep Wireless`, `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`.

Comment: @Rob The same "page" should tell you how to add information.

Comment: The driver is not installed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)

Comment: Were there any error messages when you installed the drivers?

Comment: no, there weren't. Installed successfully

Comment: You wireless adapter works now according to the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after following the instructions from "[Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers)" and before giving the output demanded by Eduardo Cola, I did `dhclient` once again and it actually finished its job after reconnecting.

The connection has been stable now for several minutes (much more than before), so if this is not one of those time windows after which the connection drops again, we may be able to declare success. In that case the question is a duplicate after all - My apologies, I did not find it before. Thanks a lot for helping!